# Magento 2 new instance redirecting to staging site

Tags: magento2, frontend, redirect-url, staging

I have my magento 2 staging site setup in folder staging and on url stagingexample.com , I have created a new folder newSetup in staging folder and setup copy of staging site in newSetup. 
I want to access the new instance of site as stagingexample.com/newSetup.

The homepage and admin panel of stagingexample.com/newSetup and stagingexample.com/newSetup/admin are working fine.

But, on frontend all the pages are redirecting to stagingexample.com/page_url only.

Please provide a solution.

Comment: This could be an issue with your .htaccess  in the root installation. If you have a magento install in the root folder, and another in a subfoler beneath root the .htaccess files will collide.You will have to add a rewrite rule that excludes your subfolder. `RewriteRule ^(newSetup)($|/) - [L]`

Comment: Please check the base url in website scop.

Comment: @tecjam  I added the rewrite rule in my root magento htaccess but there is no effect.

Comment: @SaphalJha I have checked the base urls in admin configuration, they are fine. How to check the scope ?

The issue is only at frontend. 
Homepage is rendering correct but rest all the pages from homepage redirects to staging site.